# Is there always a 1-to-1 relationship between DOM elements and HTML elements?

Tags: html, dom, web, browser

Is it possible for an element to exist in the DOM but not in the HTML? Vice versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course!

1. JavaScript manipulates the DOM, so it can remove and add elements without them being in the source code.
2. Your browser will automatically add missing elements to the DOM like omitted `<html> <head> <body> <tbody>` and a bunch of other elements.
3. Shadow DOM is a special case of DOM (for example, the controls on a `<video>` element is shadow DOM).

Comment: But won't the browser change the HTML to reflect the changes it is making to the DOM?

Comment: Nope. If you view source on a page, you'll see the original HTML source, no DOM alterations there. You can see the DOM alterations using the respective browser's developers tools (with Chrome, F12)

Comment: Okay, thanks! So in Chrome Developer Tools, the "Elements" tab shows the current state of the DOM (which can be updated by user-written JavaScript or automatically by the browser, as you mentioned), while the "Sources" tab shows the HTML source code as it was initially loaded and parsed by the browser. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes...

Check following code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("Page is loaded");
    var t = document.getElementById("test");
    alert (t.innerText);
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="myFunction()">
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<myElement id="test"> dffsdsf </myElement>
</body>

</html>
```

myElement is not html tag...

Comment: Nick - does above answers your question ?

Comment: Are you saying that the "myElement" element will not be added to the DOM by the browser because it will not recognize the myElement tag as valid HTML?

Comment: The element gets added to DOM... I had tried onclick=, class= on myElement with no issues... So, myElement is my custom tag completely recognized by browser... However, it has compatibility issues with IE...

Comment: Sorry, I think I got your question wrong... I think what you are trying may not be possible...